# Active Class of <a> unable to fetch inside repeated <li> element

Tags: html, css, web

what is wrong with this code? I am unable to execute upon click of active tabs.

```
.sample-4.sample li:nth-child(1) a.nav-link.active ~ li:last-child:after{transform:translateX(-290%)}
 .sample-4.sample li:nth-child(2) a.nav-link.active ~ li:last-child:after{transform:translateX(-104%)}
 .sample-4.sample li:nth-child(3) a.nav-link.active ~ li:last-child:after{transform:translateX(-90%)}
 .sample-4.sample li:nth-child(4) a.nav-link.active ~ li:last-child:after{transform:translateX(0%)}

.sample .nav.nav-tabs li:last- 
 child:after {
   content:'';width:100%;height:3px;background- 
   color:green;display:block;
   bottom:-4px;
   transform:translateX(0);
   transition:all .5s linear
 }
```

If I am using like below Code is working fine.

```
 .sample-4.sample li:nth-child(1) ~ li:last-child:after{transform:translateX(-290%)}
 .sample-4.sample li:nth-child(2) ~ li:last-child:after{transform:translateX(-104%)}
 .sample-4.sample li:nth-child(3) ~ li:last-child:after{transform:translateX(-90%)}
 .sample-4.sample li:nth-child(4) ~ li:last-child:after{transform:translateX(0%)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the `pseudo-class` `after` without `content`. You must have `content` in order to render `before` or `after` to DOM.
Example:

```
li:last-child:after{
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  display: block;
  transform:translateX(-290%);
}
```

Also, don't forget to change display to `block` or `inline-block`. This way your dimensions (`width`, `height`, `margin` and `padding`) will take effect.

Comment: li:last-child:after{
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  display: block;
  transform:translateX(-290%);
} I have already declared this class. But the problem is i want to move this content on the click of active <a> tag among different tabs. Thanks.